# Print array on a different page than the class it's into

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have this array and I want to print it somewhere else.
I have stored it in a user.class.php but I want to print it in feedback.php.

How do I do this? Because it keeps on telling me that it doesn't know '$myarray'.

Please help :) Thanks.

```
public function getFeedback($p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php"); //open db

    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT FeedbackPatient FROM tblFeedback 
                WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid."";

        $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

        while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $myarray[] = $row['FeedbackPatient'];
            print_r($myarray);
        }
        mysqli_free_result( $result );
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just make it a return of the function:

```
public function getFeedback($p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php"); //open db

    $myarray = array();
    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT FeedbackPatient FROM tblFeedback 
                WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid."";

        $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

        while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $myarray[] = $row['FeedbackPatient'];
        }
        mysqli_free_result( $result );
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $myarray;
}
```

Then in `feedback.php`:

```
$myarray = $user->getFeedback($user_id);
if($myarray) {
  // do something with $myarray
  print_r($myarray);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to just print one of the arrayrows? :) I tried print_r($myarray[0]), but that doesn't work.

Comment: @KimWouters Realized I left that stray `print_r` in from the original code, so that may be way. Otherwise your sql query could be failing or not returning any rows

Answer (score 0):

If `myarray` is an attribute of the class `user`, then in your feedback.php page, you would need:

1. An instance of the class `user` (e.g. `$user = new user();`)
2. Access `myarray` by using this syntax: `$user->myarray`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to serialize and store the array in a session variable:

```
$data = serialize($myarray);
$_SESSION['data'] = $data;

var_dump($_SESSION['data']);

var_dump(unserialize($_SESSION['data']));
```